# Is it safe, judicious to clean wired keyboards with hair dryer on cold setting or vacuum cleaner?

Tags: keyboard

Is it safe, judicious to clean wired keyboards with hair dryer on cold setting or vacuum cleaner?

I'm too cheap to buy compressed air. I have Dell keyboard like

[image]

[I shall use  ROOM TEMPERATURE air on hair dryer](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7909/how-to-clean-the-inside-of-a-desktop-computer-without-a-vacuum)

> A hair dryer *on the cold setting* will do the job nicely and good quality ones will even allow you to adjust the strength of the air flow.

But I see mixed messages cause [hobbes wrote](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2409/how-to-clean-crevices-of-electronics-without-compressed-air)

> This is not safe: the moving air can build up a static charge that can destroy sensitive electronic components. See [electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/39220/…](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/39220/cleaning-circuits-with-compressed-air)

Right under, [n00dles](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2409/how-to-clean-crevices-of-electronics-without-compressed-air#comment20036_2415) wrote

> @Hobbes There *are no* sensitive electronics in a standard keyboard. Nothing that static will affect anyway. Other devices, maybe.

Comment: I use a clean 2 or 5 cm wide paintbrush, turning the keyboard (or laptop) upside-down while brushing. It does an excellent job, can be used in an office where a vacuum would make noise, and produces very little static electricity. If static is a concern, *very* slightly dampen the brush with water from a spray bottle.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it'd be safe for external keyboards in general. Unless you have some high-end keyboard I doubt there will be an issue.

For laptops keyboards I'd be more careful. They sit on top of sensitive circuit boards & its possible a big crumb could short things out. However moving the laptop on a certain day could also move that crumb over to short things out.

My advice: disconnect the keyboard or power-off the laptop, shake it while it's turned upside down, & have away at a COLD air dryer. Maybe give it one more shake after the air dryer is off before reconnecting & you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Its not "safe" from the POV if damaging a keyboard, but it is fairly low risk - especially considering how cheap replacement keyboards are.

Your main risk, I imagine would be dislodging keys (although if it doesn't get swallowed in a vacuum cleaner you can normally clip them back).

I am skeptical of a hairdryers ability to dislodge that much gunk due to the low pressure. I have (fully knowing the risks) used an air compressor ON MOTHERBOARDS multiple times without issue - I did on occasion even do it at a gas station - and never had an issue. In fairness I live in a humid climate so the risk here is more of water damage - but I've never had an issue.

As others have mentioned the electronics in a keyboard are minimal, and physical switches are very big and robust (from a static handling pov) compared to other electronic components.